# Executive Summary

Tags: templates

I want to present an executive summary of a project I'm working on to my company and boss, i.e., I want to deliver a couple of pages that do not look like an article, but at the same time look nice and do not look like a high-school paper.

Are there any special templates for this?  I know there are A LOT of templates for academia work (I have even contribute to them), but I want something more... "professional" let's say and less "scholar".

Some examples that seem interesting:

[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HThJ2.jpg)

[This two](http://www.google.pt/imgres?um=1&sa=N&biw=1360&bih=677&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=gSL431C6lZS90M:&imgrefurl=http://www.docstoc.com/docs/58257113/Free-Executive-Summary-Template&docid=fGma60d4MfWRDM&imgurl=http://img.docstoccdn.com/thumb/orig/58257113.png&w=1125&h=1500&ei=NprNUdr1EdSv7AbZroHgCg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:44,s:0,i:232&iact=rc&page=2&tbnh=193&tbnw=145&start=15&ndsp=32&tx=48&ty=75)

[This three](http://www.google.pt/imgres?start=137&um=1&sa=N&biw=1360&bih=677&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbnid=pxIzOmvg8iEM6M:&imgrefurl=http://www.parasians.com/&docid=ZmRoYkBuw-qMgM&imgurl=http://parasians.com/images/ParasiansLLC_OnePageSummary_Sample_small.jpg&w=264&h=339&ei=R5rNUb7lFafW7Qbnt4CwCQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:54,s:100,i:166&iact=rc&page=6&tbnh=176&tbnw=137&ndsp=32&tx=67&ty=66#imgdii=pxIzOmvg8iEM6M%3A%3B1yqCbOp3lnsoSM%3BpxIzOmvg8iEM6M%3A)

Comment: You can't get more 'professional' than 'scholarly'.

Comment: See a [real-world example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17471132/static/professional.pdf).  What were you looking for?

Comment: @SeanAllred I hear you :), but unfortunately the CEO is highly allergic to it.  The example you provided looks really nice, but still has that "paper-like" flavor.  I think double column should be avoided to dodge it

Comment: Perhaps you could upload/point to an existing executive summary that has the look/feel you're going for?

Comment: @SeanAllred That's the thing, I'm not currently aware of any, and I was hoping someone had already came up with this issue

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://i.imgur.com/vyvuAPN.jpg)?  One of the first few relatively non-ugly results from a Google Image search for "executive summary".

Comment: @SeanAllred Kind of getting there... :)

Comment: Perhaps any number of extant [MS Office templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/project-overview-statement-TC001141413.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA001123215)?  It would be helpful to browse such a collection and see what would suit.

Comment: `\usepackage{wordlike}` (only half joking).

Comment: Hahahaha @AlanMunn I know... this is exactly why I'm asking for help here

Comment: As it stands, this isn't going to get an answer. It's not really clear exactly what at a TeX level is required in an answer: 'looks good' or similar is also opinion more than anything. I think we need more specific requirements to have a hope of an answer.